# response ebay categories data not returning json data

Tags: php, json, curl, categories, ebay-api

I am getting return `ebay` categories data but not properly formated, i want to response in `JSON` format,

```
<?php 
   $app_id="xxxxxxx";
   $dev_id ="xxxxxxx";
   $cert_id="xxxxxxx";
   $call_name="GetCategoryInfoRequest";
   $token="xxxxxxxx";
   $site_id = 0;
   $compat_level=819;

  $xml_request ="<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<GetCategoryInfoRequest xmlns='urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents'>
   <CategoryID>-1</CategoryID>
   <RequesterCredentials><eBayAuthToken>".$token."</eBayAuthToken>
    </RequesterCredentials>
   <IncludeSelector>ChildCategories</IncludeSelector>
</GetCategoryInfoRequest>";
$endpoint = "https://api.ebay.com/ws/api.dll";



    $headers = array(
        'X-EBAY-API-COMPATIBILITY-LEVEL: 819',
        'X-EBAY-API-DEV-NAME: '.$dev_id,
        'X-EBAY-API-APP-NAME: '.$app_id,
        'X-EBAY-API-CERT-NAME: '.$cert_id,
        'X-EBAY-API-CALL-NAME: GetCategories',
        'X-EBAY-API-OPERATION-NAME: GetCategories',
        'X-EBAY-API-RESPONSE-ENCODING:JSON',
        'X-EBAY-API-SITEID: 0',
        'Content-Type:text/XML'
    );

    $xmlRequest = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>";
    $xmlRequest .= "<GetCategoriesRequest xmlns=\"urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents\">";
    $xmlRequest .= "<RequesterCredentials>";
    $xmlRequest .= "<eBayAuthToken>{$token}</eBayAuthToken>";
    $xmlRequest .= "</RequesterCredentials>";
    $xmlRequest .= "<CategorySiteID>0</CategorySiteID>";
    $xmlRequest .= "<DetailLevel>ReturnAll</DetailLevel>";
    $xmlRequest .= "</GetCategoriesRequest>";
    $xmlRequestEncode = ($xmlRequest);
```

when I request to `ebay` using `curl`(above), I am getting unformatted category response data like this(below), I am getting below category response data from `ebay api`, I can't read response data but it is not `JSON` formatted, I want a `JSON` response data. Any suggestion ?

> 2015-09-09T10:24:56.505ZSuccess933E933_CORE_APICATALOG_17621198_R1truetrue200811Antiques20081truetrue379032Antiquities20081truetrue379083The
>   Americas37903truetruetrue1629223Byzantine37903truetruetrue1629233Celtic37903truetruetrue379053Egyptian37903truetruetrue1629163Far
>   Eastern37903truetruetrue379063Greek37903truetruetrue1629173Holy
>   Land37903truetruetrue1629183Islamic37903truetruetrue911013Near
>   Eastern37903truetruetrue668343Neolithic &
>   Paleolithic37903truetruetrue379073Roman37903truetruetrue1629193South
>   Italian37903truetruetrue1629203Viking37903truetruetrue1629213Reproductions37903truetruetrue1711693Price
>   Guides & Publications37903truetruetrue734643Other
>   Antiquities37903truetruetrue47072Architectural &
>   Garden20081truetrue1629253Balusters4707truetruetrue1629263Barn
>   Doors4707truetruetrue1629273Beams4707truetruetrue379093Ceiling
>   Tins4707truetruetrue635163Chandeliers, Fixtures,
>   Sconces4707truetruetrue1629283Columns &
>   Posts4707truetruetrue1629293Corbels4707truetruetrue379103Doors4707truetruetrue635173Finials4707truetruetrue635183Fireplaces
>   &
>   Mantels4707truetruetrue47083Garden4707truetruetrue379113Hardware4707truetrue379124Door
>   Bells & Knockers37911truetruetrue379144Door Knobs &
>   Handles37911truetruetrue379164Door Plates &
>   Backplates37911truetruetrue1629334Drawer
>   Pulls37911truetruetrue1629344Escutcheons & Key Hole
>   Covers37911truetruetrue1629354Heating Grates &
>   Vents37911truetruetrue379134Hooks &
>   Brackets37911truetruetrue379154Locks &
>   Keys37911truetruetrue1629304.................... and many more

Comment: Try adding header `X-EBAY-SOA-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: JSON` to your `$header`.

Comment: still it is not working,not displaying JSON format